spring object automatically generates properties by get method？
In the process of stability governance, it was found that a Get method did not have corresponding properties, but when returning data to the frontend, it automatically generated a property to return to the frontend。
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@ApiModel("库存返回结果")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class StockProduct {


    @ApiModelProperty(name = "stockInfo", value = "库存")
    private List<Stock> storeInfo;


    public List<Stock> getStoreInfo2() {
        List<Stock> result = new ArrayList<>();

        return result;
    }
}

Return data to the front-end
{
    "storeInfo": [
        {
             
        }
    ],
    "storeInfo2": [
        {
             
        }
    ]
}

Why is this?
I have seen that the compiled class file did not generate the storeInfo2 attribute

I found the reason. This method is called when fastjson is serialized
